# Microstrategy Developer too slow

Tags: development-environment, microstrategy

I am trying to connect to an MSTR intelligent server in Seattle from MSTR Developer running on my laptop connected in Bangalore. It takes an average of 10+ seconds for any action I do on the developer, like, login or open folders or open a report or anything. It is almost impractical to do any report development this way (not to mention the frustration).

When my colleague connects to the same instance/project from Seattle he doesn’t face any delays. So I figure that this is a network issue and doesn’t have much to do with the metadata or indexes. The network response time to the box is 30ms and 300ms average from Seattle and Bangalore respectively. I found online that 280ms is average response time from India to US. Accessing the reports and projects via the web interface is smooth though.

Have you ever experienced a situation like this before? Can the network delays cause that much trouble on MicroStrategy? Please help…

> PS: This question is not quite a fit for SO. But I guess that MSTR
>   developers face this problem normally and may be they know a fix.
>   Hence posting this here rather than SU or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common problem, in my experience. I believe that MicroStrategy's network traffic is XML based, so network bandwidth as well as latency is an issue.

Usually, the web server is more responsive because:

- It is performing "simpler" tasks that Developer
- The network-intensive traffic is between I-Server and web server, so if they're colocated, performance will be reasonable.

I'm afraid I've never come across an effective solution to this issue. Having a "jump server" in the same data centre as the MSTR servers, with the Developer software installed, is usually the most tolerable solution (provided Remote Desktop isn't too laggy).

Comment: I have used numerous client server applications (mostly Microsoft based) in the past where client and server were at opposite sides of the planet. Never faced an issue like this before.. :( Is there anything that MSTR is doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Same solution here : we have developpers VMs on a host in the same datacenter as the server, and we remote desktop them. From there, we use Developper/object manager, etc
You can still do 90% of the tasks in web.